# How can I using ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator to send my message with websocket

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-messaging

I have a concurrent issue, my WebSocket was used spring-message,
when my chatroom has a lot of people it will very slow.

So I try to find how, and I found some problem where the WebSocketSession using sendMessage, it has a synchronized in class websocketServerSockJsSession

```
@Override
public void sendMessageInternal(String message) throws SockJsTransportFailureException {
    // Open frame not sent yet?
    // If in the session initialization thread, then cache, otherwise wait.
    if (!this.openFrameSent) {
        synchronized (this.initSessionLock) {
            if (!this.openFrameSent) {
                this.initSessionCache.add(message);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

so if they have 200 chat in one second it will be very slow,

I found the implement of WebSocketSession call ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator.

But I can't cast WebSocketServerSockJsSession to ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator, I can't find how to set my WebSocketSession.

I can't change the sockJS.

So how can I do if I use the sockJS and I want to use ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator method?

is another way to implement the ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator sendMessage or I can do some property setting and make my WebSocketSession turn to ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator?

[image]

this my config setting

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableWebSocket
public class SpringWebSocketConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements WebSocketConfigurer {
@Override
public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addHandler(webSocketHandler(), "/websocket/send").addInterceptors(new HandshakeInterceptor()).setAllowedOrigins("*");

    registry.addHandler(webSocketHandler(), "/websocket/sockjs").addInterceptors(new HandshakeInterceptor()).setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As its name suggests, the `ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator` is a **Decorator**.

This decorator overrides some functions such as `sendMessage` of `WebSocketSession`, and `WebSocketServerSockJSession` performs its actions through its `webSocketSession`, so changing `webSocketSession` to `ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator` can solve the problem.

```
ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator currentWebSocketSessionDecorator = new ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator (session, 1000, 1024);
wsSockJsSession.initializeDelegateSession((WebSocketSession)concurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator);
```